# Gradle. Say dependency to use another version of already included dependency

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, gradle-dependencies

Example:

```
implementation(group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-remote-driver', version: '3.13.0')
implementation(group: 'com.mypack', name: "old-library", version: '1.0')
```

Problem is that `old-library`  throws 
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/SessionNotFoundException` which is missing in newer selenium versions.
Unfortunately I have no access to source code. 
Question - is it possible to say only for `old-library` to use old selenium version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, that's not possible. as I get from the Gradle Slack chat:

> than there is no way to solve it without dependency package relocation
>
> actually, in this case problem not even on classpath level, because if 2 dependencies have the same id Gradle have to choose one of them.
> If you change only dependnecy id, you will have problems on runtime, because 2 dependencies with many conflicting classes will be on the same classpath. It’s valid for Java, but which version will be choosed on classpath resolution depends on classloader and you cannot rely on this